# Session.equals no longer (fully) reactive? [Meteor]

Tags: meteor

I need to `if` on the value of a Session variable in a reactive computation, and have the computation rerun when the value changes. According to the [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session_equals) this use case is ideal for `Session.equals`. So far so good, thus I have in my reactive computation code which calls `Session.equals` as in:

```
if (!Session.equals(key, undefined)) {
   // now I know 'key' is defined
   ...
}
```

The code used to work well but for some reason it stopped doing so. Now (in ver METEOR@1.3.2.4) I'm noticing issues where although the Session value for `key`changes, the reactive computation does not get rerun.

In one of my attempts to figure out the cause I've replaced the code with:

```
if (!!Session.get(key)) {
   ...
}
```

Which works - the computation is now getting rerun when expected!

Can anyone tell why would `Sesssion.get()` work, but not `Session.equals()`?

Could be relevant: the value of the Session variable changes but it is always 'defined' (e.g. from one non-empty string to another). Would that be sufficient to re-trigger the computation? IOW, maybe `Session.equals` is 'clever' enough to know the value changed from one defined value to another defined value, thus it establishes that a computation rerun isn't necessary, which causes the issue I'm experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

You have actually answered it yourself.
Session.equals is an optimised version which reruns the computation only if the value has changed. Now as the value doesn't change from 'defined', it won't rerun the computation.

Comment: I suspected that would be the case, but I couldn't quite figure out how they'd implement that. They'd need to evaluate and compare the value of the Session key given to `Session.equals()` to the 2nd parameter, externally. Assuming that's the case, they'd need to store the compared reference to the value somewhere in the computation. But, how can they assume that the value of the 2nd parameter hasn't changed in the meanwhile?